# Python 3.x unintended TypeError Phonebook

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Phone_book: #Please note that this line of code has no indentation, all other lines has at least one indentation.

    def __init__(self):
        self.phoneDic = {}                                         
        commandsDic = { "add" : self.add , "lookup" : self.lookup , "alias" : self.alias,
                        "change" : self.change , "save" : self.save,
                        "load" : self.load , "quit" : self.i_quit }

        while True:
            a = input("Phone book")
            b = a.split() #Splits a line of text into list items
            try:
                commandsDic[b[0]](*b[1:]) #Allocates
            except TypeError:
                print("This function does not work")                           
            except KeyError:
                print("You have written an incorrect amount of arguments")
            except SystemExit:
                print("Exiting...")
                break 

    def add(self, allonym, digit):
        print("Name:", allonym, "\nNumber", digit, "\nSaved in phone book!")
        self.phoneDic[digit] = [allonym]


    def encounter(self, allonym):
        found = 0
        phno = 0
        for digit, allonyms in self.phoneDic.items(): 
            if allonym in allonyms:                  
                phno = digit
                found += 1
            if found == 0:
                return 0
            elif found == 1:
                return phno
            else:
                return -1   

     def alias(self, allonym, newallonym):
        if newallonym:
            phno = self.encounter(allonym)
            if phno > 0:
                self.phoneDic[phno].append(newallonym)
                print("Alias stated")
```

The intention of the function `alias` is to create a nickname to the allonym itself and be saved in the memory together with the allonym. I do not get the function to work as I get TypeError. How would one mitigate the error and make the alias get saved and paired with allonym?

Execution

```
Input: 
Phone bookadd Bromley.Jones 12345
Output: 
Name: Bromley.Jones 
Number 12345 
Saved in phone book!
Input: 
Phone bookalias Bromley.Jones BJ
Output: 
This function does not work.
```

Allonym has the same linguistic definition as name.
Allonyms has the same linguistic definition as names.

Comment: In `encounter`, Shouldn't the last `if found == 0:....` block be outside the `for` loop?

Comment: Both (your indentation comment) ways work without getting one of the defualt errors(undefined etc.). However, the output remains the same.

Comment: Apparently, the problem is here: `if phno > 0:`. The keys in the dictionary are strings but you are comparing to integer. Either change the keys to ints, or change comparison to `if int(phno) > 0:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems. First, in `encounter`: it will always return `0` unless the item you are searching for is the first one because the `if` block is inside the `for`. You can simply return it once it is found:

```
def encounter(self, allonym):
    for digit, allonyms in self.phoneDic.items():
        if allonym in allonyms:
            return digit
    return 0
```

However, one issue here is related to the second problem: the keys in the dictionary are strings, but you are treating as ints. I would change the above function to return `None` when not found. Then in the `alias` function:

```
def encounter(self, allonym):
    for digit, allonyms in self.phoneDic.items():
        if allonym in allonyms:
            return digit
    return None

def alias(self, allonym, newallonym):
    if newallonym:
        phno = self.encounter(allonym)
        if phno:
            self.phoneDic[phno].append(newallonym)
            print("Alias stated")
```